# Git clone subdirectory into Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having hard time checking out a GitHub sub directory as a project into Android Studio. I could clone the main directory:

[main repository](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises)

But I really need to clone one of the subproject(because these sub folders looks like an actual project directory):

[sub directory](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/tree/student/Lesson01-Favorite-Toys/T01.01-Exercise-CreateLayout)

[image: github sub directory]

I tried cloning main directory into my Android Studio workspace, but then I cannot run my sub projects since I cannot set common path for `androidmanifest.xml` (since there are multiple sub projects with different manifest files in each sub directory).

I would like to know if there's a way I can :

- Clone the main directory, and able to run each sub directory as different project in Android Studio, or
- Clone only sub directory, and clone them one by one whenever I want to execute them.

I have searched on Stack Overflow for a solution and found that sparse checkout won't work for Android Studio, however none of them answers my case specifically.
Right now relying upon **downloading** the main repository and importing sub-directory as project in Android Studio. I would like to know if there's another way around as mentioned above.

Comment: how about clone the whole main directory (using command line, for example) and load the project you want in android studio ?

Comment: That would be just like the **download** option I do right?

Comment: @Rahul Raj How did you resolve this issue?